# operator precedence for function called by namespace in piping

Tags: r, namespaces, dplyr, piping, magrittr

Please someone could explain why there is a difference in the behaviour of the last line of code, when I call a function using its namespace in a pipe, and what the error message actually means:

```
library(magrittr)
1:5 %>% cumsum
#### [1]  1  3  6 10 15
1:5 %>% cumsum()
#### [1]  1  3  6 10 15
1:5 %>% base::cumsum()
#### [1]  1  3  6 10 15
1:5 %>% (base::cumsum)
#### [1]  1  3  6 10 15
1:5 %>% base::cumsum
#### Error in .::base : unused argument (cumsum)
```

I genuinely thought that it would work since [operator precedence rules](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) state that the highest priority is for the namespace operator `::`, far away from special operators.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because it calls the description of the function, `base::cumsum` returns `function (x)  .Primitive("cumsum")` which does not take any argument, which is what the error says. Once you add the `()` as you see a line above, it calls the function with the `1:5` argument.

Even better example is with your own function.

```
foo<-function(){cat("hello")}
```

then returns its code if called without argument:

```
    > foo
function(){cat("hello")}
```

So it is similar with `base::cumsum`, but I guess it is somehow protected or just programmed that is gives you that description.

Comment: thanks, but it's still kind of "obscure" to me what this primitive function does exactly... you say that when we specify the namespace of the package it's not the same function?

Comment: sort of, yes. if you dont put the `()` then it is not treated as a function in sense of passing it an argument regardless of calling it from its `namespace`. it's like if you just type the name of a variable, then it gets printed out. Now some description of the function gets printed out, hence does not expect you to pass it an argument and throws an error if you try it.

Comment: that's weird because when i run `str(cumsum)` and `str(base::cumsum)` i get the same thing. Do you have any doc to read on this subject by chance?

Comment: Yh I would expect that, because you are calling the function 'description'. I think even better is if you write your own function and then call it without the brackets. `foo<-function(){cat("hello")}` returns exactly the contents of it. unfortunately, don't have any precise documents, just personal experience, sorry. Maybe someone else will contribute?